# Rounded corners with soft edges

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, pictures, visual-effects

MS Word 2010: I can make soft edges (rectangle) or rounded corners (insert picture as fill in an auto shape) but I haven't figured out how to do both.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it amazing, how sometimes articulating a question gets you thinking in a more creative way and voilà, you're unstuck.

I was trying to use "artistic effects."  It turns out that after filling the autoshape, the next step is "picture effects" in "Picture Styles".